# Manually apply f.lux settings to directly to monitor

Tags: display, colors, external-display, f.lux, displaylink

I recently started my first full-time job (web development), and I've read that applying slight f.lux color settings even during the day can greatly reduce eye strain. I would like to do this, but my two external monitors are connected to my laptop via DisplayLink, which doesn't support color profiles and f.lux does not work with them.

Is there a way to apply f.lux-like settings directly to the monitors themselves? My monitors allow for me to manually set RGB and contrast/brightness.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, reducing the blue RGB setting on your monitor will affect you the same as when f.lux is engaged. The thought is that blue light [keeps you awake](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21552190) and [contributes to eye strain](http://www.gunnars.com/how-they-work/) more than other colors. Worth a shot.

Somewhere there is a way to get RGB adjustment percentages from color temperature (which f.lux uses), but I don't think the problem requires that kind of precision. I'd set it to look like f.lux, then adjust the blue up/down every few days to see what works best for your eyes.